# Templates inside Templates in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

This should be simple, but I can't find an answer.

I have two simple handlebars templates as follows:

```
<template name="streams">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            {{#each streamItems}}
                {{> stream}}
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="stream">
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

And some Meteor js as follows:

```
Template.streams.streamItems = function () {
  return [
    {title: "Stream One Title"},
    {title: "Stream Two Title"}
  ];
};
```

Right now this combo throws an error, but when I replace the call to the "stream" template with the content from that template it works.

```
<template name="streams">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            {{#each streamItems}}
               <div class="span4">
                  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
               </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there any way to get this to work with the separate templates?

Comment: I just tried your example and it works fine (http://cl.ly/2S3O2h2z3t020B3x0j1e). What error are you getting?

Comment: Tom, thanks. Did you try with the set of two teimplates or the second? When I try the first version, the app crashes with the weird Meteor error log that doesn't tell me much

Comment: I literally copied your (first) html + js into a clean meteor project, and ran it and it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm... Okay, there must be something wrong with my install. I've some other peculiar errors. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Wandering Digital, Did you find an answer to this? It would be helpful to mark the question as answered if you can. Helps people sort through the unanswered questions :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a server error—solved with a reinstall.